# Reporting exceptions into New Relic for non-IIS .NET apps

Tags: windows-services, newrelic

I've got a windows service application that I would like to push errors from into New Relic, since we use it for all our other (web application) error monitoring.  The [New Relic Agent API docs](http://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/AgentApi) say that this can be done with the `NoticeError(System.Exception)` method. And according to [this doco](http://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/AgentDocumentation#configuration), I just need to set an environment variable named `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` and put two `appSetting` values in which I've done, but still nothing is showing up in New Relic.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

The NoticeError() API method can send errors from background processes to New Relic, but there are a few configuration settings that can prevent data being sent or recorded correctly. To find the problem I'd need to see your configuration file, the code that's using NoticeError(), some logs from your agent when that code is firing, and preferably your New Relic account. To get all that privately, I'd like to ask you send us a support ticket with us at https://support.newrelic.com/

If you link to this question in the ticket, we can post the fix if it's not specific to your code.